# Ionic icons through error due to "Content Security Policy."

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, content-security-policy

The strange thing is happening from one day to another.

All of a sudden, I get this error to my Ionic app, which is caused by ion-back-button, and for other ion icons too.

Here is the error:

```
Refused to connect to 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' class='ionicon' viewBox='0 0 512 512'><title>Arrow Back</title><path stroke-linecap='square' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='48' d='M244 400L100 256l144-144M120 256h292' class='ionicon-fill-none'/></svg>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback. Note that '*' matches only URLs with network schemes ('http', 'https', 'ws', 'wss'), or URLs whose scheme matches `self`'s scheme. data:' must be added explicitely.

(anonymous) @ polyfills.11e22041d02a3781.js:1
polyfills.11e22041d02a3781.js:1 Refused to connect to 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' class='ionicon' viewBox='0 0 512 512'><title>Arrow Back</title><path stroke-linecap='square' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='48' d='M244 400L100 256l144-144M120 256h292' class='ionicon-fill-none'/></svg>' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.
```

Here is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
    "@hetznercloud/ngx-translate-mock": "^0.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/ble": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/bluetooth-le": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.32.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^5.33.1",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.1.0",
    "@ionic/cordova-builders": "^6.1.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "4.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "colors": "^1.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ble-central": "^1.2.5",
    "cordova-plugin-bluetoothle": "^4.5.14",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^3.21.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.3.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  }
```

Comment: Please, could you show us the tag `<ion-icon>` that have the SVG icon, how it is declared on your html page? Thanks!

Comment: hey @EvertonCosta, thank you for your interest. I answered my own question :)

Answer (score 0):

I updated my ionic 5 to ionic 6

Ionic 5 index.html file is like this:

```
<head>
  ...
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="font-src 'self' data:; img-src * data:; default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'">
  ...
</head>
```

Ionic 6 index.html file does not contain the content-secutiry-poliy meta

Deleting this line resolved the problem.

No security issues since Ionic team itself deleted this constraint.

Comment: just to elaborate on this: font-src 'self' data:; is whats required here to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding 'data:' to my connect-src
like this:

```
<meta 
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
  content="
    default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
    connect-src 'self' data:;
    font-src 'self' data:;
    img-src * data:; 
">
```